# What Excel function do I use for this?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Basically I just want the correct formula for G3 in this sheet based off the values input into the D column:

[image]

So in the example the addition would be (2 + 8 + 1 + 8 + 2) = 21. I've tried looking this up but I'm unsure to the wording so it's been hard to find any solutions. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Cecil. Do you mean `=SUM(D2:D6)`?

Your question doesn't quite match the example - it has `8` in place of your image which has `4`.

Comment: You need to improve your question , col c sums to 31 and col d to 13 neither match the total shown of 21.

Comment: I'm not trying to sum any of these columns. The numbers in the D column are only just referencing the numbers in the C column. So user enters 4, but as the columns A-C show, 4 is just a replacement for 8. So the function needs to match the user input number to the number in the A column and then *USE* the number in the C column and make a total.

Answer (score 1):

To add the values in those shaded cells in column D , type the following into G3:

```
=SUM(D2:D6)
```

Comment: So what I want is the first column to be the numbers referenced in D. So for example, D2, the user inputs the number 2. Number two is equal to 2 and then in D3 the user inputs the number 4, and the number 4 is equal to 8. So the total is taking the number input by the user and finding the number in column A and using the number in the column C and summing those numbers. Does that make sense? I appreciate the comment though!

Comment: It is sort of a confusing problem, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out! I just used VLOOKUP in a backend sheet and then used that to get the total for the numbers I'm wanting. I appreciate the help!

Comment: You'd want to use `=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(D2:D6,A2:C6,3,FALSE))`